# Taking backup of files using XCOPY

Tags: windows, backup, batch, xcopy

I have a file_list where the paths of the source files are saved.

```
ex: 

file_list

 -c:\SAY\hello\world.txt

 -c:\SAY\hello\New\file.txt
```

Using for loop i tried copying the files which are in the `file_list` to the destination

```
ex:

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in (file_list) DO (

xcopy /i/y "%%A" "D:\hi\hello\"
```

I want `"c:\SAY\hello\New\file.txt"` to copy `"D:\hi\hello\New\file.txt"`

Here i can able to copy the files but the folder structure is not same.It is copying `\New\file.txt` inside `D:\hi\hello\` itself.But i want it to create a folder structure and copy inside `D:\hi\hello\New\`

Comment: Try `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=\" %%A in (file_list) DO (xcopy /i/y "%%A\%%B\%%C" "D:\hi\%%C")`

Comment: The folder structure depth makes no sense. Exclusion - the built command line length exceeds its limitation.

Comment: The comman you have provide will work, but can you please make it from backside of the path? instead of removing first two folders from the path ?

Comment: No. The path depth is unknown. And I don't understand the aim of this.

Comment: Hi AKina, Your input helped me .Thanks alot :). For your clarification i am trying to take back up of files before moving the latest files to the folder.